# Mysql order query by index

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am running an mysql query and I am trying to order the results by there auto incrementing index value. I am running my query with this code.

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chanels WHERE videolocation != '' ORDER BY index DESC ");
```

This worked before I added the ORDER BY function and now when I run a mysql_num_rows test it is returning 0 rows.  If you have any ideas thank you I appreciate it.

Comment: For God's sake, don't use `mysql_` functions, they're not supported since YEARS! Use `mysqli_` or PDO.

Comment: I know this I have to go back and change all my code do u know a good reference to use to adapt my code to mysqli. Is the syntax much different?

Comment: `mysqli` has a procedural interface which is quite similar to the old and unmaintained `mysql`

Comment: Just a note on coding style - you should avoid using `SELECT *` in your statements unless you really, really need it. Its better to select exact columns you need - for future compatibility and also to reduce resource consumption if you possibly don't need every single column.

Comment: Thanks @Flavius. Can't wait to go back and change all that haha.

Comment: @RandomWhiteTrash I know but in this instance I needed to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you sure that the column is called `index`? That is not an ideal choice for a column name because it is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html). Normally the auto-increment column should be called `id` or similar.

If you really *have* called your column `index` then you need to quote it using backticks in your SQL queries:

```sql
SELECT * FROM chanels
WHERE videolocation != ''
ORDER BY `index` DESC
```

Comment: Thank you that is correct should have known that I will give u credit when it allows me in 9 minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit yoru code like this

```
 $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM chanels 
                        WHERE videolocation != '' 
                        ORDER BY 'index' desc");
```

may it helps you